# Segmenation fault while calling wait_for and get of valid future pointer

Tags: c++

I get sometimes a segmentation fault in the following code while executing wait_for or get, it's very different. But most times it works. Here you have an example:

```
// Object.h

#ifndef OBJECT_H
#define OBJECT_H

class Object
{
  public:
    Object();
    Object(const Object& orig);
    virtual ~Object();
  private:

};

#endif /* OBJECT_H */

// Object.cpp

#include "Object.h"

Object::Object()
{
}

Object::Object(const Object& orig)
{
}

Object::~Object()
{
}

// main.h

#include <cstdlib>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include "Object.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector<future<Object*>> asyncFutures;
    vector<tuple<Object*, Object*, future<Object*>*>*> runningFutures;
    int i=0;
    int cores=thread::hardware_concurrency();
    while((runningFutures.size()>0)||(i<100))
    {
        if(i<100)
        {
            Object* a=new Object();
            Object* b=new Object();
            asyncFutures.push_back(async(launch::async, [](Object* paramA, Object* paramB)
            {
                return new Object();
            }, a, b));
            runningFutures.push_back(new tuple<Object*, Object*, future<Object*>*>(new Object(), new Object(), &asyncFutures.at(asyncFutures.size()-1)));
        }
        if(runningFutures.size()>0)
        {
            while(runningFutures.size()==cores-1)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<runningFutures.size(); i++)
                {
                    cout << i << endl;
                    future<Object*>* future_ptr=get<future<Object*>*>(*runningFutures.at(i));
                    if(future_ptr!=nullptr)
                    {
                        cout << "Valid Pointer" << endl;
                        bool v;
                        future_status fs;
                        bool r=false;
                        v=future_ptr->valid();
                        if(v)
                        {
                            cout << "Valid Future" << endl;
                            fs=future_ptr->wait_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));
                            r=((v)&&(fs==future_status::ready));
                            if(r)
                            {
                                cout << "Ready Status" << endl;
                                Object* o=future_ptr->get();
                                cout << "Result" << endl;
                                runningFutures.erase(runningFutures.begin() + i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea, where the segmentation fault could come from? Finally, the pointer as well as the future must be valid before calling wait_for or get and they are not changed in between. Because only this thread accesses the futures. The future is created using async and launch::async.

Comment: `&asyncFutures.at(asyncFutures.size() - 1)` - bad idea. As `asyncFutures` grows ti wil be resized, as in so doing that address becomes dangling garbage. Any plans on utilizing it are folly.

Comment: The reason for the seg fault has already been explained when you asked the [same question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340465/segmenation-fault-in-wait-for-and-get-of-valid-future-pointer).

Comment: Unfortunately I have so solving for that problem. I must save the future anywhere for multithreading. How can this be done if not as in the example?

Comment: The error comes also with using back instead of `at` and `size`

Comment: That's because you still don't understand what we said here, or in the prior question. `std::vector` can, and will, reallocate it's *entire* memory backdrop during an expansion operation. When that happens, any/all *addresses* you took from the vector sequence are now completely bogus. They're broken; they're invalid; they're dangling garbage. Any dereference of those invokes *undefined behavior*. You really have two choices. use a sequence that is pointer/iterator safe from expansion reallocation (there aren't many, `std::list` is one), or rethink how you're storing your futures as a whole.